# how to empty the first select option with form api?

Tags: forms

I have made two select fields with the form api d7

and i need to make it required and the first option is null to force the user select both

i tried with #REQUIRED #EMPTY_VALUE OPTION  but gives error unsupported operands

i see the validation function may help but my case have an ajax request based on the first select to get the values of the second

so i need to make it required and the first is null

the code answer

```
 $form['gov']=array('#title'=>'Gov','#name'=>'governorate'
,'#type'=>'select','#options'=>$options,'#ajax'=>array('callback'=>'ajax_callback',
'event'=>'change','wrapper'=>'replace'
  ,'method'=>'replace'));

 $form['city']=array("#title"=>'City',
'#name'=>'city','#type'=>'select'
,'#prefix' => '<div id="replace">',
'#suffix' => '</div>','#options'=>$op);
```

also the ajax request only happens one time

Comment: could you provide your code sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the input required you need to use `#required => TRUE`, and if you wants to add a empty default value you need to add a value to your `#options` like 
`'' => t('Please select')`

See [Form API Reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#select)

Comment: i did as u mentioned and reviewed the form api and see that issue is a bug in drupal so needs help from others faced the same problem

Comment: Your `ajax_callback` function returns an array? This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903073/ajax-form-validate-and-submit) may help you.

Answer (score 5):

Add a empty value setting to the form array:

```
$form[$key] = array(
  ..
  '#empty_value' => '',
  ..
);
```

That will add a `- Select -` option to the list that will not pass a required validation if the user leaves it on `- Select -`.

Don't add an empty value to the #options array `'' => t('Please select')`. That will still pass a required validation if the user leaves that option selected.